# Visual Studio Team Services isn't Displaying Published Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, publish, azure-pipelines

We have been using Visual Studio Team Services for about 2 years now with great success.  It seems that in recent months something happened to the display of unit test metrics/results.  I used to see drill down information for the tests that were published but now that has disappeared.  In addition I now see this strange JSON text where unit test information used to be.  I've searched high and low for an answer to this and came up empty.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Weird JSON Blob where Unit Test stuff used to be]
[image: Unit tests showing no Test Results]

Comment: The json blob is caused by the installation of the Contributions  Guide extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-samples.samples-contributions-guide

Comment: Can you share the (structure of) the Build definition and can you check whether your test results are created on the server as a file? And what test framework + tasks are you using?

Comment: Can you also share or check your build log to see if the test result is published successfully?

Comment: Here is my MSTest Command:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:"D:\VSOBuilds\60905\SHARP Enterprise\SHARP-CI-DB\src\Dev\Databases\Sharp.Database.Tests\bin\debug\Sharp.Database.Tests.dll" /resultsfileroot:"D:\VSOBuilds\60905\SHARP Enterprise\SHARP-CI-DB\src\Dev\Databases\TestResults" /publish:"<valid url hidden>" /publishbuild:"SHARP-CI-DB_20160519.4" /flavor:Debug /platform:"Any CPU" /teamproject:"SHARP Enterprise"

Then all Unit tests run

Comment: Here is the result verifying publish: And here is the result stating publish was successful:
Summary
-------
Test Run Failed.
Passed  1999
Failed     4
------------
Total   2003
Results file:  D:\VSOBuilds\60905\SHARP Enterprise\SHARP-CI-DB\src\Dev\Databases\TestResults\tfsbuild_SDHQTFSBUILD104 2016-05-19 16_29_05_Any CPU_Debug.trx
Test Settings: Default Test Settings
Waiting to publish...
Publishing results of test run tfsbuild@SDHQTFSBUILD104 2016-05-19 16:29:05_Any CPU_Debug to <valid url hidden>...
.........Publish completed successfully.

Comment: To answer Eddie's question:   `code` <Exec IgnoreExitCode="true" Command= "&quot;$(MsTestExeLocation)&quot; /testcontainer:&quot;$(SolutionRoot)\$(BranchToBuild)\Databases\Sharp.Database.Tests\bin\debug\Sharp.Database.Tests.dll&quot; /resultsfileroot:&quot;$(SolutionRoot)\$(BranchToBuild)\Databases\TestResults&quot; /publish:&quot;$(TFSUri)&quot; /publishbuild:&quot;$(BuildNumber)&quot; /flavor:Debug /platform:&quot;Any CPU&quot; /teamproject:&quot;$(TeamProject)&quot;" WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot)\$(BranchToBuild)\Databases\Sharp.Database.Tests\bin\debug"/>`code`

Answer (score 0):

I can get the same behavior as you when publish the test result via MSTest or VSTest.Console. I have help you submit a feedback on MS Connect Page, you can track it here: [Published test result does not show in Build Summary Report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2740759/published-test-result-does-not-show-in-build-summary-report).

And for now, you can use the "Publish Test Result" task in vNext build to publish the test result, it can get the test result displayed in build summary.

Answer (score 0):

After switching away from XAML builds to the new build system this problem was resolved.  Now a simple Unit test step was added with the appropriate properties setup and it worked like a champ.